# Rx packets being discarded

Tags: packet, fiber, packet-loss

last month my apartment was connected to fiber optics but a problem keeps occurring that occasionally every 5-10 minutes my internet would freeze for a few seconds, tried to switch the router, the connector between the router and the fiber optic cable and nothing seems to work. Today i have taken a look at the router settings and found that a TON of RX packets are discarded.

Any clue why that could happen?

[Router settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBNE9.png)

Comment: Your modem actually indicates 0 errors have occurred. Bytes being discarded is normal

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of possible reasons. These are the most common:

1. The packet size exceeded the MTU and the DF bit was set.
2. Packets aren't leaving the router fast enough and it ran out of resources to hold the received packets.
3. The packets were sent to a VLAN that the port was not configured to receive.
4. Excessive fragmentation and fragments received out of order or spread way apart in time.

If you find the count goes up every time you see the freeze, then I'd say this is a victim of the freeze. The router can't get packets out for some reason, so they get dropped at the interface.

A common cause of this problem is a duplex mismatch on another interface. Make sure autonegotiation is enabled on both sides of all modern Ethernet links. Do not lock speeds or duplexes unless you know *exactly* what you're doing.